# Altima 2017 S outside tempreture stuck on -40F

Tags: nissan, altima, dashboard

[image: Dashboard display indicating -40]

Can someone tell me what is the location of sensor? Or what's the issue?

Comment: I would contact Nissan, as the car should have 3 years of warranty. Of course that may depend on where you live.

Comment: The ambient temperature sensor on vehicles is usually located on the front of the vehicle near the grill so that it's not reading too much engine heat

Comment: Here you go, https://youtu.be/ZIlzW1pM9X4 which gives you an idea of what it looks like and where its located

Comment: So once you find it, look for corroded connections or broken wires...